# post-hoc analysis for logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, post-hoc

Suppose our dependent variable Y is TRUE vs FALSE, and our independent variable X is GREEN, YELLOW, and RED. We performed a logistic regression of Y~X. I wonder if it is possible and how to use the trained logistic regression to answer the following question:

- What is the odds ratio (and p-value) of TRUE vs FALSE for subjects whose X equals to GREEN.
- What is the odds ratio (and p-value) of TRUE vs FALSE for subjects whose X equals to YELLOW.
- What is the odds ratio (and p-value) of TRUE vs FALSE for subjects whose X equals to RED.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible.  Using 0/1 to indicate False/True, $x=1$ to indicate red, and $w=1$ to indicate green, the model is

$$ \operatorname{logit}(p) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 w$$

Here, we have set the reference group to be yellow. Note the following

- $ \beta_0 $ Is the log odds for the yellow category, and hence $\exp(\beta_0)$ is the odds of yellow.
- $\beta_0 + \beta_1$ is the log odds of the red group.  The odds of red is then $\exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1) = \exp^{\beta_0} \cdot \exp^{\beta_1}$
- A similar argument can be made for green.

As for p-values, this depends on what the null hypothesis is.  Typical logistic regression output will report p values for the Wald test that $\beta_j$ is 0.  If you edit your question to be more specific about the associated null for the p value in question, I can be more precise.

Comment: Thanks! So we can calculate the odds of TRUE vs FALSE, but not the odds Ratio of TRUE vs FALSE, for category GREEN. Right? If this is correct, can you please tell me how to interpret the p-value of the coefficients?

Comment: No, you certainly can calculate the odds ratio for green, it is a similar process as red.  The p value is the probability of observing a test statistic more extreme than what we saw, assuming the null was true and all our background assumptions were true.

Comment: Lets us RED as an example. The odds ratio is the ratio of two odds. Can you please tell me what are the two odds to calculate the odds ratio of RED group?

Comment: I understand what the odds of RED is, but I don’t get what the odds *ratio* of RED is.

Comment: @WCMC. The odds ratio for red would be $\exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1)$.  The odds for yellow would be $\exp(\beta_0)$.  The odds ratio for red is then $\exp(\beta_1)$.